# vb.net how to reject users input if its not an integer

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a program that takes a users input. I'm trying to reject their input if it is a decimal or a letter. How do I do this?

```
Function GetHowLongToRun() As Integer
    Dim Years As Integer
    Dim valid As Boolean = False
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Plant Growing Simulation")
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("You can step through the simulation a year at a time")
    Console.WriteLine("or run the simulation for 0 to 5 years")
    Console.WriteLine("How many years do you want the simulation to run?")
    Do
        Console.Write("Enter a number between 0 and 5, or -1 for stepping mode: ")
        Years = Console.ReadLine()
        Try
            If Years > -2 And Years < 6 Then
                valid = True
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Enter a whole number between 0 and 5, or -1 for stepping mode: ", Years)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Enter a whole number between 0 and 5, or -1 for stepping mode: ")
            GetHowLongToRun()
        End Try
    Loop Until valid
    Return Years
End Function
```

Comment: Console.ReadLine() returns a string, not an Integer.  Improve your code by using Integer.TryParse() to make the conversion.  The compiler can help you find mistakes like this when you put Option Strict On at the top of the source file.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here:

1. `Console.ReadLine()` will **always** return a `string`, but it's immediately assigned to an `Integer` value. That this compiles at all speaks to an *extremely* poor practice where `Option Strict` is turned off. Better to use any one of `Integer.Parse()/TryParse()`, `Convert.ToInt32()`, or `CInt()`.
2. The code is handles failure in two different ways: with a loop *and* by re-calling the function. The latter option can cause a never-ending recursion cycle, which can ultimately create an uncatchable- StackOverflowException situation.

To fix it, you can remove the extra `GetHowLongToRun()` call in the exception handler. The loop will already ensure the code tries again. But I'd go further and isolate the input to it's own function in a more-generic way:

```
Public Function ReadInteger(ByVal Prompt As String, ByVal InvalidPrompt As String, ByVal Retries As Integer, Optional ByVal MinValue As Integer = 0, Optional ByVal MaxValue As Integer = Integer.MaxValue)
    Dim attemptCount As Integer = 0
    While attemptCount < Retries
        Console.Write(Prompt)
        Dim input As As String = Console.ReadLine()

        Dim result As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(input, result) Then
             If result >= MinValue AndAlso result <= MaxValue Then
                 return result
             End If
        End If

        Console.WriteLine(InvalidPrompt)
        attemptCount += 1
    End While    

    Throw New InvalidOperationException()
End Function
```

Then you can call the new function from the original like this:

```
Function GetHowLongToRun() As Integer
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the Plant Growing Simulation")
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine("You can step through the simulation a year at a time")
    Console.WriteLine("or run the simulation for 0 to 5 years")
    Console.WriteLine("How many years do you want the simulation to run?")

    Return ReadInteger("Enter a number between 0 and 5, or -1 for stepping mode: ", "Invalid input.", 3, -1, 5)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to check if the input matches your requirements. This is convenient because you can check for multiple conditions in one statement.

You will first need to include the regex library:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Then create a regex object, specifying the desired pattern as the constructor parameter:

```
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("\d+")
```

This regex pattern **\d+** will identity strings that have 1 or more sequential digits. Regular expressions are powerful and you can modify the pattern to be more specific if you'd like. There is a lot of documentation online.

Using the Regex object's 'Match' method, you can then test strings to see if they match the specified pattern. This returns an object of type 'Match':

```
Dim match as Match = regex.Match(Years)
```

Lastly, check to see if the match succeeded using the match object's 'Success' property.

```
If match.Success Then
    valid = True
End If
```

Alternatively, you could parse your input string into an integer. If the parsing fails, you know it was not a valid input:

```
If Integer.TryParse(Years) Then
    valid = True
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

comments and explanation in line

```
Dim Years As String = Console.ReadLine()
Dim HowLongToRun As Integer = GetHowLongToRun(Years)

Function GetHowLongToRun(input As String) As Integer
        Dim valid As Boolean = False
        Dim ValidYears As Integer
        Do
            '.TryParse not only tests for a valid number and returns True or False but
            'if it finds a valid number it will assign it to the second parameter
            'The AndAlso portions of the If will not be evaluated unless the first portion is True.
            'This is called short-circuiting.
            If Int32.TryParse(input, ValidYears) AndAlso ValidYears < 6 AndAlso ValidYears > -2 Then
                valid = True
            Else
                'You are misusing the (String, Object) overload of Console.WriteLine
                'This is meant as a sort of variation on String.Format where the second parameter
                'is substituted for a place holder in the string like {0}
                'Since there is no placeholder, I deleted the , Years
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Enter a whole number between 0 and 5, or -1 for stepping mode: ")
                input = Console.ReadLine
            End If
        Loop Until valid
        Return ValidYears
End Function
```